# MutationObserver with specific mutations

Tags: javascript, events, mutation-observers

I am currently trying to use the [MutationObserver API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/MutationObserver) to fire a message (which later will be functions) based on class change of an element.

I'm currently firing a log on mutation change, but I'm assuming there are mutations such as DOM position etc that are firing. Is there a way to make the `MutationObserver` only look for specific `attributes` in this case the `class`?

As primarily a Drupal developer I'm used to using jQuery and that's why I have the classList function as I like chaining.

Here is my code:

```js
var foo = document.getElementById("foo");
var wrapper = document.getElementById("wrapper");

var observer = new MutationObserver(function(mutations) {
    mutations.forEach(function(mutation) {
        if (mutation.attributeName === "class") {
         var attributeValue = mutation.target.getAttribute(mutation.attributeName);
            console.log("Class attribute changed to:", attributeValue);
        }
    });
});

function classList(el) {
  var list = el.classList;
  return {
      add: function(c) { 
         if (!list.contains(c)){
            console.log('Contains: '+list.contains(c));
           list.add(c); 
         }
         return this;
      },
      remove: function(c) { 
         if (!list.contains(c)){ 
            list.remove(c); 
         }
         return this; 
      }
  };
}

observer.observe(foo,  {
    attributes: true
});

wrapper.addEventListener("scroll",function(){
    classList(foo).add('red').remove('yellow');
    if(wrapper.scrollTop > 500){
         classList(foo).add('yellow').remove('red');
    }
});
```

```css
#wrapper {
  height: 200px;
  overflow: scroll;
}
#foo {
  height: 1000px;
}
```

```html
<div id="wrapper">
   <div id="foo">Element</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Use `attributeFilter: ['class']` as per documentation?

Comment: Classic case of having a grown ups look there. Thank you @wOxxOm

Comment: @wOxxOm Should I delete the question? Or will you move your comment to an answer and I'll accept that?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Although @wOxxOm answered my question(negligence) in his comment, I applied the functionaily and realised that I no longer needed a forEach as I was only expecting a singular attribute, so the finished(test) code looks like:

```js
var foo = document.getElementById("foo");
var wrapper = document.getElementById("wrapper");

var observer = new MutationObserver(function(mutation) {
    console.log('Current class:' + mutation[0].target.className);
});

observer.observe(foo, {
    attributes: true,
    attributeFilter: ['class']
});

wrapper.addEventListener("scroll",function(){
    if(wrapper.scrollTop > 500){
        if(!foo.classList.contains('yellow')){
           foo.classList.add('yellow');
           foo.classList.remove('red');
        }
    } else {
        if(!foo.classList.contains('red')){
           foo.classList.add('red');
           foo.classList.remove('yellow');
        }
    }
});
```

```css
#wrapper {
  height: 200px;
  overflow: scroll;
}
#foo {
  height: 1000px;
}
```

```html
<div id="wrapper">
   <div id="foo">Element</div>
</div>
```

I have tidied up the mutation observer to find the class name. I removed my function to allow me to chain the class elements, as I came across an issue where it was triggering the mutation even when the class was not changed, just because the element was being returned.